# JavaScript how to concat two nulls or undefined and return null

Tags: javascript

Assuming the value firsName and lastName comes from some data source. The value sometimes could be both null or both undefined. fullName concats the two.

```
let a = {};
let b = {
    fullName: a && a.firstName+' '+a.lastName
};
console.log("fullName is "+JSON.stringify(b.fullName)); // fullName is "undefined undefined"

a = {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null
};
b = {
    fullName: a.firstName+' '+a.lastName
};
console.log("fullName is "+JSON.stringify(b.fullName)); // fullName is "null null"

b = {
    fullName: {...a.firstName, ...' ', ...a.lastName}
};
console.log("fullName is "+JSON.stringify(b.fullName)); // fullName is {"0":" "}

b = {
    fullName: {...a.firstName, ...a.lastName}
};
console.log("fullName is "+JSON.stringify(b.fullName)); // fullName is {}
```

My current solution is

```
const getFullName = (firstName, lastName ) => {
    if ((typeof firstName == "undefined" || firstName === null) && (typeof lastName == "undefined" || lastName === null)) {
            return null;
    }
    else { 
        return firstName+' '+lastName
    }
}

b = {
    fullName: getFullName(a.firstName, a.lastName)
};
console.log("fullName with function is "+JSON.stringify(b.fullName)); // fullName with function is null

a = {};
console.log("fullName with function is "+JSON.stringify(b.fullName)); // fullName with function is null
```

Is there a better way to make b.fullName have a value of null (without writing a function)?

Comment: Well, a function is probably the better way right now, given that you are dealing with two variables and you want to concatenate them. You could have shorter code but it's still going to be more complex than a single operator and thus would always benefit from being in a function. You could, however, generalise the function to concatenate any amount of strings, so it's at least not only usable for two names

Comment: What happens if `firstName` **or** `lastName` is null/undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would be a better solution:

```
return [firstName, lastName].filter(it => !!it).join(" ") || null
```

Beware, that this will also include "" as null/undefined, and avoid including "null" in the string if you provide one but not the other. In general this is probably desirable for the function you are writing.

Eg: `getFullName("John", null)` would return "John"

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of dealing with it using a ternary.

```js
const fName = undefined;// undefined;
const lName = undefined;

const fullName = (fName || lName) ? `${fName||""} ${lName||""}`.trim() : null;

console.log(fullName);
```

And here we use `destructuring` with  `default` values.

```js
const person1 = {
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: undefined
}

const person2 = {
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: undefined
}

const displayName = ({firstName: f='', lastName: l=''}, {x: fn} = {x: f+' '+l}) => {
  fn = fn.trim();
  console.log((fn==='') ? undefined : fn);
}


displayName(person1);
displayName(person2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases where it's beneficial to use the loose equality operator, as `null` and `undefined` are [loosely equal to each other, but to nothing else](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/).  You could then simplify your conditional to:

```
const getFullName = (firstName, lastName ) => {
    if (firstName == null && lastName == null) {
        return null;
    } else { 
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a very good simple way to do this. You can shorten the code needed:

```js
let firstName = null;
let lastName = undefined;

let fullName = ((firstName || "") + " " + (lastName || "")).trim() || null;

console.log(fullName)
```

Which isn't very pretty. A very slightly better code might be

```js
let firstName = null;
let lastName = undefined;

let fullName = [firstName, lastName].filter(s => s != null).join(' ') || null;

console.log(fullName)
```

However, it's still a cumbersome to repeat it a lot of times.

Instead, you can still use a function and generalise it to any amount of parameters, so you can reuse it later in other places:

```js
const combine = (...strings) => strings.filter(s => s != null).join(" ") || null;

console.log(combine("Alice"))
console.log(combine("Bob", null))
console.log(combine("Fred", "Bloggs"))
console.log(combine("Samuel", "L", "Jackson"))
```

If you want to also generalise the delimiter, you can easily do that through partial application:

```js
const combine = (delimiter = " ") => (...strings) => strings.filter(s => s != null).join(delimiter) || null;

const combineNames = combine();
const combineCSV = combine(",")

console.log("--- names ---")
console.log(combineNames("Alice"))
console.log(combineNames("Bob", null))
console.log(combineNames("Fred", "Bloggs"))
console.log(combineNames("Samuel", "L", "Jackson"))

console.log("--- comma separated values ---")
console.log(combineCSV("Alice"))
console.log(combineCSV("Bob", null))
console.log(combineCSV("Fred", "Bloggs"))
console.log(combineCSV("Samuel", "L", "Jackson"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it too difficult, which is fine.  I always do that myself.  However, let me suggest a simple solution:

```
const getFullName = (firstName, lastName ) => {
    firstName = firstName || "";
    lastName = lastName || "";
    if ( firstName != "" && lastName != "" ) {
        return firstName & " " & lastName;
    }
    else if ( firstName == "" && lastName == "" ) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return firstName || lastName;
    }
}
```

It basically turns `undefined` and `null` into Empty Strings, and then it just deals with the Empty Strings.  Either you've got both names, neither name, or only one.

Comment: There's a typo in your answer, `firstName & " " lastName;` should probably be `firstName + " " + lastName`

Answer (score 0):

`return firstName?lastName?firstName+' '+lastName:null:null;`

Comment: Nested ternary operators are difficult to read - outside of code golf I would personally avoid them

Answer (score 0):

Another oneliner could be

```
const getFullName = (firstname, lastname) => (firstname || '' + ' ' + (lastname || '')).trim() || null
```

Explanation:

`firstname || ''` if `firstname` is evaluate as nullable value (`0, '', null, false, undefined, NaN...`) it will print an empty string.
Then we concatenate with a white space and we do the same operation.
Care, this time i encapsulate the operation between bracket because of the left/right evaluation in JS
Trim the result if it's an empty string it will return null else it will return firstname or lastname or both

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest format.

You concatenate the two values. If there is no value then we default to an empty string. And then trim the result. If there is nothing left then return `null`.

What this does not allow is an empty string for both the first and last name.

```js
function makeName(f, l) {
  return `${f||''} ${l||''}`.trim() || null
}

console.log(`[${makeName()}]`);
console.log(`[${makeName('', '')}]`);
console.log(`[${makeName('John')}]`);
console.log(`[${makeName('John', 'Smith')}]`);
```